# PHP if specific business day of week and time echo

Tags: php, echo

The following code works to echo "Open" or "Closed" if time is between 8:15am and 5:30pm. I am trying to make it day specific. How can I incorporate format character 'D' as example, Mon hours 8:15am - 5:30pm .. echo "Open", Sat hours 8:15am - 1:00pm "Open". I want to be able to control echo of Open/Closed by each day and time.

current working code for hours only

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$hour = (int) date('Hi');
$open = "yah hoo, we are open";
$closed = "by golly, im closed";

if ($hour >= 0815 && $hour <=1735) {
// between 8:15am and 5:35pm
echo "$open";
} else {
echo "$closed";
}
?>
```

example of what I am trying to do:

```
$hour = (int) date('D Hi');
if ($hours >= 0815 && $hour <=1735 && $hour === 'Mon')
{ echo "$open"; }
else { echo "$closed"; }
if ($hours >= 0815 && $hour <=1300 && $hour === 'Sat')
{ echo "$open"; }
else { echo "$closed"; }
```

another example per The One and Only's answer which looks close to what I am looking for, but this also does not work

```
<?php
$openDaysArray = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat','Sun');

$thisDate = date('D Hi');

$explode = explode(" ", $thisDate);
$day = $explode[0];
$time = $explode[1];

if (in_array($day, $openDaysArray)) 
if ($time < 815 || $time > 1730 && $day === 'Mon');
if ($time < 815 || $time > 1730 && $day === 'Tue');
if ($time < 815 || $time > 1730 && $day === 'Wed');
if ($time < 815 || $time > 1730 && $day === 'Thu');
if ($time < 815 || $time > 1730 && $day === 'Fri');
if ($time < 815 || $time > 1730 && $day === 'Sat');
if ($time < 815 || $time > 1730 && $day === 'Sun');
{echo 'Open';}
else {echo 'Closed';}
?>
```

Comment: `0815` will be treated as octal by PHP, because of the leading zero; and it's an invalid octal number, so it will be treated as a zero

Comment: And you're casting $hour to an int, so it can ___never___ be `Mon` or `Sat`

Comment: Why not use a second variable for the day? And wrap `'` around your numbers.

Comment: Build an array of opening times indexed by day of week... `['Mon' => ['open' => 815, 'close' => 1735], 'Tue' => ['open' => 815, 'close' => 1800], ....];` then get the `$day` (as a day short name) and `$time` values, and use that for a lookup in your array

Comment: @Mark, thanks, I removed the (int) still trying to figure it out. Do you know how to right it?

Comment: Only checked answers own the points;)  but dont click my answer, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd handle it this way. Set up an array of all your open times.  If you know you're closed on Saturday and Sunday, there's really no need to proceed with with checking times at that point, so kill the process there first.  Then simply find out what day of the week it is, look up the corresponding opening and closing times in your `$hours` array, create actual DateTime objects to compare (rather than integers).  Then just return the appropriate message.

```
function getStatus() {

    $hours = array(
        'Mon' => ['open'=>'08:15', 'close'=>'17:35'],
        'Tue' => ['open'=>'08:15', 'close'=>'17:35'],
        'Wed' => ['open'=>'08:15', 'close'=>'17:35'],
        'Thu' => ['open'=>'08:15', 'close'=>'22:35'],
        'Fri' => ['open'=>'08:15', 'close'=>'17:35']
    );

    $now = new DateTime();
    $day = date("D");

    if ($day == "Sat" || $day == "Sun") {
        return "Sorry we're closed on weekends'.";
    }

    $openingTime = new DateTime();
    $closingTime = new DateTime();

    $oArray = explode(":",$hours[$day]['open']);
    $cArray = explode(":",$hours[$day]['close']);

    $openingTime->setTime($oArray[0],$oArray[1]);
    $closingTime->setTime($cArray[0],$cArray[1]);

    if ($now >= $openingTime && $now < $closingTime) {
        return "Hey We're Open!";
    }

    return "Sorry folks, park's closed. The moose out front should have told ya.";
}

echo getStatus();
```

Comment: Must say thats a proper and clean way to do it, but 3 instances and 2 method calls for just testing some numbers and a char(3) :-) But in the end i would prefer that the OP uses this answer. ;)  AlwaysLearning did you here me...

Comment: Sure it could definitely be a lot simpler.  But I kind of wanted to show some logic.  And maybe it's just me, but when dealing with dates and times, I prefer to keep them as dates and times.  Just preference.  There's always a more efficient way. Cheers.

Comment: Thats fully ok and fine (i noted i prefer), but im that kind of dev that has to handle huge amount of data and i try always to keep the `overhead of any kind` low :) Cheers too.

Comment: @Robert Wade, I keep getting HTTP Error 500 with your code. It is clean.

Comment: I just pasted it directly into phpfiddle.org and it works just fine. Check your error logs to see if you might have some other piece of code causing an issue.

Comment: @Robert Wade - syntax error, unexpected '[' line 5. Tried removing them, then more errors. You are right, it does work in phpfiddle. Maybe a different PHP version? I am going to see which PHP version I am using.

Comment: Can you post the full code of that php page somewhere that you're getting the error on line 5?  What is on line 5 of your code?

Comment: I copied and pasted your same code above. line 5 is the 'Mon' => line code.

Comment: @Robert Wade, Im on PHP version 5.2 and phpFiddle is on 5.4, that would explain why [] is not working. I updated to 5.4 and it works fine now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a switch statement:

```
$thisDate = date('D Hi');

$hoursOfOpArray = array("Mon_Open" => "815", "Mon_Close" => "1730", "Tue_Open" => "815", "Tue_Close" => "1730"); //repeat for all days too fill this array

$explode = explode(" ", $thisDate);
$day = $explode[0];
$time = (int)$explode[1];

switch($day) {
    case "Sun":
        $status = "Closed";
    break;
    case "Mon":
        $status = ($time < $hoursOfOpArray[$day . "_Open"] || $time > $hoursOfOpArray[$day . "_Close"]) ? "Closed" : "Open";
    break;
    //same as Monday case for all other days
}

echo $status;
```

This should also work:

```
echo ($day === 'Sun' || ($time < $hoursOfOpArray[$day . "_Open"]) || ($time > $hoursOfOpArray[$day . "_Close"])) ? "Closed" : "Open";
```

Comment: One, thanks - but I am trying to get everyday individually. This way if Monday is 8:15-5:30pm and Saturday is 8:00am-1:00pm, I can change each day to the open/closed times.

Comment: Just change the values inside $hoursOfOp Array - this is your "controller" and found in 1 location

Answer (score 0):

This one works, added remarks to explain as much as possible.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// Runs the function
echo time_str();

function time_str() {

    if(IsHoliday())
    {
        return ClosedHoliday();
    }           

$dow = date('D'); // Your "now" parameter is implied

    // Time in HHMM
    $hm = (int)date("Gi");

    switch(strtolower($dow)){
            case 'mon': //MONDAY adjust hours - can adjust for lunch if needed
                if ($hm >=    0 && $hm <  830) return Closed();
                if ($hm >= 830 && $hm < 1200) return Open();
                if ($hm >= 1200 && $hm < 1300) return Lunch();
                if ($hm >= 1300 && $hm < 1730) return Open();
                if ($hm >= 1730 && $hm < 2359) return Closed();
                break;
            case 'tue': //TUESDAY adjust hours
                if ($hm >= 830 && $hm < 1730) return Open();
                else return Closed();
                break;              
            case 'wed': //WEDNESDAY adjust hours
                if ($hm >= 830 && $hm < 1730) return Open();
                else return Closed();
                break;              
            case 'thu': //THURSDAY adjust hours
                if ($hm >= 830 && $hm < 1730) return Open();
                else return Closed();
                break;              
            case 'fri': //FRIDAY adjust hours
                if ($hm >= 830 && $hm < 1730) return Open();
                else return Closed();
                break;              
            case 'sat': //Saturday adjust hours
                return Closed();
                break;              
            case 'sun': //Saturday adjust hours
                return Closed();
                break;              

    }           
}

// List of holidays
function HolidayList()
{
// Format: 2009/05/11 (year/month/day comma seperated for days)
return array("2016/11/24","2016/12/25");
}

// Function to check if today is a holiday
function IsHoliday()
{
// Retrieves the list of holidays
$holidayList = HolidayList();
// Checks if the date is in the holidaylist  - remove Y/ if Holidays are same day each year  
if(in_array(date("Y/m/d"),$holidayList))
{ 
    return true;
}else
{
    return false;
}   
}

// Returns the data when open
function Open()
{
    return 'Yes we are Open';
}

// Return the data when closed
function Closed()
{
    return 'Sorry We are Closed';
}   

// Returns the data when closed due to holiday
function ClosedHoliday()
{
    return 'Closed for the Holiday';
}

// Returns if closed for lunch
// if not using hours like Monday - remove all this
// and make 'mon' case hours look like 'tue' case hours
function Lunch()
{
    return 'Closed for Lunch';
}

?>
```

Comment: That should have been as an edit http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39520107/edit in your question and to have pinged that person. If this isn't a solution, it should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$o = ['Mon' => [815, 1735], /*and all other days*/'Sat' => [815, 1300]];
echo (date('Hi')>=$o[date('D')][0] && date('Hi')<=$o[date('D')][1]) ? "open": "closed";
```

Done! And dont ask.

Comment: If you are not using PHP7  change all `[]` with `array()` in the first line

Comment: *"If you are not using PHP7"* - You mean, *"If you are using PHP < 5.4"*. All versions after 5.4 and before and including 7 support `[]`.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Ops, year you are right, its late here and just dumped that from mind. Mixed the `myfunc()['field']` stuff with array syntax :)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, thanks, I did not know how to address that, I edited the original question and removed it as an answer.

Comment: This answer is fine and well for code golf but this probably isn't suitable for production code.

Comment: @Mr. Llama I only dumped that becuse of the disco. in the comments in all answers/question, i prefer others answers too. And `production code` mmmh never see any production code on SO. Only good explainations about it ;) But u are fully right.